# Javafx using directory chooser crashes app under linux

Tags: java, linux, javafx-8

I am experimenting a problem with DirectoryChooser class. I writed the code under Windows and tested it and works so fine. I have runned .jar compiled under my Ubuntu 16.04 computer and when the DirectoryChooser.showDialog() method is called, the application crashes. I tried to debug it, and the exactly point when crashes is in the returned valor assignation, this is:

```
File file = fc.showDialog(primaryStage);
```

I tried without assign to the file variable and dialog is showed correctly, but obviously I don't have the folder path :/.

I put the entire code:

```
private EventHandler<MouseEvent> onLblFolderMouseButtonReleased = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        if(event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY){
            DirectoryChooser fc = new DirectoryChooser();

            if(screenshotsSaveDir != null && screenshotsSaveDir.isDirectory()){
                fc.setInitialDirectory(screenshotsSaveDir);
            } else {
                fc.setInitialDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
            }

            fc.setTitle(rb.getString("select_folder_dialog_title"));
            File file = fc.showDialog(primaryStage);

            if (file != null) {
                prefs.put(SAVE_PATH, file.getPath());
                lblFolder.setText(file.getPath());
                screenshotsSaveDir = file;
                screenshotsSavePath = file.getPath();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

There is an exception returned, a fatal error, problematic frame: C [libpthread.so.0+0x9d84] pthread_mutex_lock+0x4

Have someone any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the problem. I am using the JNative Hooks library. I used it in past projects and all works fine under Linux. In this new project I used the version 2.0.3 and I started experimenting problems. I rolled back to version 2.0.2 of JNative Hooks and all works fine.